# How to nest expressions in AngularJS' views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using **Angular Material** together with **angular-translate**.

Basically when using AM's md-select I have:

```
<md-select-label>{{ userLanguage ? userLanguage.chosenLanguage: "Choose language"}}</md-select-label>
```

which shows **Choose language** if no option was selected or the selected option otherwise.

Finally I use **angular-translate** to translate all the label (e.g. "Choose language" in multiple languages) in my application's views like:

```
{{ 'LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE' | translate }}
```

However, when I try to nest the 2 expressions (ternary operator + angular-translate filter) by:

```
{{ userLanguage ? userLanguage.chosenLanguage : {{ 'LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE' | translate }} }}
```

I get invalid syntax:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/$parse/syntax

Any clue on how to deal with **nested expressions**?

Comment: Why don't you just use `<md-select-label>{{ 'LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE' | translate }}</md-select-label>`?

Comment: because that way when an option is selected, the label is not replaced. it's how md-option/md-label web components work

Comment: Try something along the lines of: `<md-select-label>{{ userLanguage ? userLanguage.chosenLanguage : ('LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE' | translate) }}</md-select-label>`

Comment: Well, you cannot nested expressions like `{{somehing, {{something else}} }}`, but maybe you can do: `userLanguage ? (userLanguage.chosenLanguage) : ('LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE' | translate)`. A fiddle as demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uxpVw/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handlebar syntax implies a JavaScript expression, or to be specific, an [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Using handlebars inside handlebars doesn't make sense because you've already told the compiler you're switching from HTML to JavaScript.

That being said, you can just rewrite your expression without the inner handlebars:

```
{{ (userLanguage ? userLanguage.chosenLanguage : 'LB_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE') | translate }}
```

Comment: This way, the value stored in `userLanguage.chosenLanguage` will be translated and I don't know if this is something the OP wants.

Comment: This solution works.
However' Nikos Paraskevopoulos and TeoMor's one is more accurate as I aim to translate the label only, not the actual selected language

Comment: True, however this is something that can be solved inside the controller or the filter, depending on what the data is and where it makes sense to fix it. Without more context it's hard to know, but knowing that it's impossible to nest handlebars is still important.

Comment: Angular-translate's filter is built in in the module. I already made changes in other modules but I believe it's always better to use "usage workarounds" rather than "behing the scenes workarounds". Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it's 'wrong' or not, but I believe markup should be as simple as possible. As soon as my HTML seems too JavaScripty I tend to use functions `{{ returnSomethingAppropriate(userLanguage) }}`